# How to pass value using a tag to another page?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i get the h1 value and td values when a tag is clicked to another page?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Book 1</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chapter 1</td>
    <td>100 pages</td>
    <td><a href="newpage.html"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How the values of h1 and td are settings?

Comment: `<a href="newpage.html?name=Book 1&chapter=Chapter 1&pages=100 pages"></a>`, ofcourse you have to url encode

Comment: Their is a scripting language called 'Php'. You can use that. :P

Answer (score 0):

The data can be traversed between pages using `GET` or `POST`. If using `GET` , you need to pass the data as `query string parameter`using `jQuery/javascript` and receive it at the other end.
If using `POST` you need to submit the form and retrieve the same on the next Page

Answer (score 0):

You need to give those tags an ID and then use JavaScript to get their value and create a link.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1 id="header">Book 1</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="val1">Chapter 1</td>
    <td id="val2">100 pages</td>
    <td><a id="link" href="newpage.html">Submit &gt;&gt;</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  function generateLink() {
    var query = "h1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("header").innerHTML)
              + "&val1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML)
              + "&val2=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("val2").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("link").href = "newpage.html?" + query;
  }

  generateLink();
</script>
```

Comment: i would rather use selector instead of id because id is not only option for this